# iOS Drawing App Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ipod

I am creating a simple drawing application in which I have a UIView in background & UIImageView in foreground. I am doing some drawing stuff in UIView and I have set an image in UIImageView. I want to add the transparency effect in UIImageView to show the lines behind the image. I know I can do this by reducing alpha, but I don’t want to change the alpha of image.

I want to do it with `CGContextSetBlendMode`, but I don’t know how to do this. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

**IMAGE** http://www.freeimagehosting.net/q3237

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];      

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply); 
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDarken alpha:1]; [imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)]; 
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeDarken); 
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: For that you need to draw image on uiview, can u post ur code so that I can suggest you what changes you need to do

Comment: i know i can do this but the problem is that whenever i do this & i set the blendmode in lines(CGPath) they overlap each other like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/UroVd.png

Comment: @Smith please edit your question to include the code you placed into the comment and remove that comment. It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to keep imageview do it like this.. 
Since you are drawing on two different context you wont be able to use blend modes across them. For that you need to draw  other stuff on your drawing view and then draw your image..

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

         // do ur drawing stuff first             

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, self.image.CGImage);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSaturation);
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect);  
  }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to convert my UIImage into CGBitmapContext? So i can apply blendmode in my image?